# Multi Column index containing all columns of another index

Tags: sql, indexing, multiple-columns, clustered-index, non-clustered-index

If I have a multi-column index - containing 2 columns, and I create a 2nd index containing those 2 columns (as 1st 2 - same order) plus an additional 3rd column. Is there a need to keep the 1st index with only 2 columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order of the two columns is the same (on the first two positions) then it makes no sense to keep the initial index. It will most probably stop being used.

By-the-way, you can keep them both for a while and build a query to check the [sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-index-usage-stats-transact-sql) table from time to time just to have this confirmed ...

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no need to keep the first index.

I should emphasize that the ordering of the columns is important.  So, this only applies when the columns in the two indexes start with the same columns in the same order.

I might add . . . there is an ever-so-slight benefit to the index with two columns and some databases might even take advantage of:  the index is smaller.  So, if you are memory-constrained (data is really big compared to available memory), then you might have some cases where the 2-column index could fit into memory but the larger index would not.  I view this is a particular edge case, and unlikely in practice.